# Django Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to generate a report across 2 models/ tables. Here they are:

```
class Members(models.Model):
    username          = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, unique=True)
    email             = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, unique=True)
    name              = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    phone             = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
```

and

```
class Report(models.Model):
    report_text    = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    reporter_id    = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    reported_id    = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    date_created   = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    date_read      = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

The 2 tables obviously have auto increment IDs as the primary key.

The report will look like this:

```
Reported Phone | Reported Name | Report | Date Reported | Date Report Read
```

Everyone reported on will be in the member table. The reporter ID is the ID of the member who logged the report. The reported_id is the ID of the person the report is on. I need to do a join across the 2 models to get the members name and their phone number. I can't quite work it out form the doc. I believe I should make the reported_id and reporter_id both foreign keys to the Members table primary key ID field. How do I do that and what code will extract the report for all entries submitted by a specific reporter?

Do I user reported_id = models.ForeignKey(Members) and do the same for reporter_id. It seems odd as I don't specify the field that the field is foreign to. The ORM is supposed to make it easier (and it usually does!). I could do it with a join in SQL but this has got me stumped.

I hope the question makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: You should definitely have `ForeignKey` fields wherever you want to denote a one-to-many relationship between your models.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do that and what code will
>   extract the report for all entries
>   submitted by a specific reporter?

Yes, do `reported_id = models.ForeignKey(Members)`

The field will be the target models primary key, which is in your case `id` since you haven't specified one.

You will need to specify a [`related_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for one of these fields to prevent a name clash for the reverse foreign key accessor.

After setting up the foreign key field, to get all objects related via that foreign key, use the `related_name` to query the related model.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

For example, if you set up your model as:

```
reporter = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name="reports_by_me")
reported = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name="reports_by_others")
```

You could access all related `Report` models via that foreign key by

```
member_instance.reports_by_me.all()
member_instance.reports_by_others.all()
```

Comment: Surely the ForeignKey should be called `reported`? That will use `reported_id` as its underlying database field.